# Will expression retain the same definition if particle is changed?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-を, relative-clauses

> 「ここにじっとしていてもしょうがない………か」

> 自分を奮い立たせるために、わざと自分の考え**を声に出し**行動を始めた。

I came across the expression 声を出す on jisho.org. I don't know if replacing the expression's を with に (because を is already used earlier in the sentence) will allow me to use the 声を出す definition when translating. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

声を出す cannot take another object because 声 itself is the object of this transitive verb. What is said as a word is not important.

声に出す is an "incomplete" expression because it lacks a direct object. It should be preceded by an object or a quotative-と to show the content of the speech. 声に itself is like an adverbial expression "as (physical) voice" or "aloud".

> - 彼は謝罪の言葉を声に出した。
> - 「ありがとう」と声に出して言いなさい。

See this question for more examples: [What does "声が出る" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19255/5010)

Comment: Then the 出し doesn't form the relative clause 出し行動?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey No. A masu-stem cannot modify a noun as a relative clause.

Comment: But in Felipe's answer below, it says " I will assume you know how to connect verbs with the "te-form. There's a more formal way to do so, which is using the dictionary form instead." I thought, based on this information, that the 出し行動 was 出して行動..... I read their answer wrong, didn't I?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey No. In this context 出し and 出して are interchangeable, but neither a masu-stem and a te-form can modify the following noun as a relative clause. A dictionary form can (strictly speaking, 連体形, not 終止形).

Comment: If neither a masu-stem/continuative form verb/adjective, or a te-form verb/adjective can modify the noun to form a relative clause, then What forms are the verbs/adjectives allowed to take as a relative clause to modify the noun????? Edit: Nevermind, saw your previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you know how to connect verbs with the "te-form":

> 晩【ばん】ご飯【はん】を食【た】べて、寝【ね】る。I will eat dinner and (then) sleep.

So, usually in texts/books, etc. There's a more formal way to do so, which is using the dictionary form instead.

> 晩【ばん】ご飯【はん】を食【た】べ、寝【ね】る。I will eat dinner, and (then) sleep.

But sometimes, writers do that without using a comma in between verbs/words, and that is what might be throwing you off. So what you have there is **声に出し、行動**. We could rewrite it as:

> 自分を奮い立たせるために、　わざと自分の考えを声に出して、行動を始めた。In order to cheer myself up, I started acting my thoughts out loud.

In your specific case though, I believe we should not use a comma, because it might be using the following pattern **声に出して＋verb/noun** that usually means **"Doing something out loud".**

> 声に出して読む - To read out loud.

Comment: Wait a minute, its possible to connect verbs via no-te form?!? I never knew this... thanks for the information.

Comment: Yes, it is still called "continuative-form" but it uses the "dictionary form" instead of the "te-form" :)

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Wait a minute, if you did not know that, why did you romove that part from your question? You were initially asking whether this 出し is a noun or a verb, but since you removed it, I thoght you were aware of that grammar :D

Comment: @naruto I think I removed it as I realized that technically speaking, the correct answer was neither a verb nor a noun; thereby making that part of the question redundant; due to 声に出し being in truth a Japanese expression.

Comment: @Toyu_Frey This 出し is a **verb** (conjugated as 連用形). It perfectly follows the standard Japanese grammar... But let's continue about this form in your other question.