# Is the 出し in the following sentence a relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

Is the 出し -which I believe to be 出す- in the following text a relative clause, as the 行動 is a noun?

> 「ここにじっとしていてもしょうがない………か」
>
> 自分を奮い立たせるために、わざと自分の考えを声に**出し行動**を始めた。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65931/5010

Answer (score 3):

No. 出し is a [**連用形**](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65953/5010), which means it **never** modifies a noun as a relative clause. 連用形 literally roughly means "continue-**verb**-form". That 出し modifies nothing. Just because a verb comes before a noun doesn't mean it's a relative clause.

Compare the following two sentences.

> 1. グラウンドを**走り**先生を呼んだ。
>    I ran across the ground and called my teacher.
> 2. グラウンドを**走る**先生を呼んだ。
>    I called my teacher who was running across the ground.

走り is a 連用形, so it does not form a relative clause. This 走り is interchangeable with 走って. On the other hand, 走る is a 連体形 (≒dictionary form), so it forms a relative clause that modifies 先生. Please review the basic grammar of relative clauses.

- [Do I have a good grasp on the basics of what the continuative form is?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65936/5010)

---

Perhaps you need some exercise. Only two of the following six sentences contain a relative clause. Can you tell which?

1. 彼はイチゴを食べ鳥を捕まえた。
2. 彼はイチゴを食べて鳥を捕まえた。
3. 彼はイチゴを食べる鳥を捕まえた。
4. 彼女は山に登るシカを見た。
5. 彼女は山に登りシカを見た。
6. 彼女は山に登ってシカを見た。

Comment: The Third and Fourth sentences form a relative clause, I think, as the verb is before the noun and in its dictionary form...

Comment: @Toyu_Frey That's correct. And that's also why 出し in your original question has nothing to do with relative clauses.

Comment: If it isn't a relative clause then what is it?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Two [independent clauses](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-independent-clauses.html) that are not directly related to each other, thus forming a [compound sentence](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/compound-sentence-examples.html). A [relative clause](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/what-is-a-relative-clause-verb.html) is a type of dependent (subordinate) clause.

Comment: So then I would translate 声に出し行動を始めた as 声に出し [connecting article, such as "and", "but" etc] 行動を始めた?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Yes, "I said my thoughts out loud *and* started off." Note that this type of masu-form has `and` built-in.